# Having embedded video from other sites in my video sitemap increases the ranking of the sites I am embedding from?

Tags: video, embed, embedded-control, video-sitemap

I have a website Mywebsite.com and I am embedding videos from site XYZ.com in my website and providing additional content like a review or anything else.

By creating a video sitemap of my site for the videos I have in it (embedded from site XYZ.com). Will the videos get indexed in video.google.com as Mywebsite.com or the website I am embedding from (XYZ.com) ?

Other than the potential thumbnail of the video displayed in the search results next to my posts in the search page will it give me any help in rankings? 
Or will it in fact favor and help the site I am taking the videos from making it look like an authority site/source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitemaps have no effect on rank at all. As well, having resources linked *from* your site to another helps the other site, not yours. Creating outbound links to resources can effect rank in a limited way if the site that is linked to is an authority, however, this does not occur, as far as I know, for resources such as images, videos, and so on. This effect is limited to pages and not page elements.

Comment: Would creating the sitemap with the video embeded content cause my websites links with the videos to be added in videos.google.com or would it cause the actual videos to be added on there? 
Sidenote: (I am embedding them on my site)

Comment: Sitemaps, as far as I know, should be only the resources on your site. If you were to include the off-site resources, I do not think there would be any harm, however, I cannot tell you whether the videos would be attributed to your site or the other. I would assume the other since they are not actually on your site. Perhaps someone here can comment. I do however, think that once the pages are fetched, then Google may index the videos as a part of your site. This is a bit of a fuzzy area.

Comment: I will leave it as is then without the video sitemap, thank you for your input.